# Why did Colonel Hans Landa let Shosana escape in the beginning?

Tags: plot-explanation, inglourious-basterds

Why did Colonel Hans Landa let Shosanna escape at the beginning of *Inglourious Basterds* if it was his duty to find and eliminate the jews at that area. I found it rare because he was proud of his job, and I'm pretty sure his job wouldn't be well evaluated if it's known that he let someone escape.

I don't think it is related to the fact he probably later used her to achieve his plan, a lot of time passed since that moment and the end of the movie.

Is it just a plot hole or could there be another more interesting reason?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As explained in the Inglorious Basterds screenplay:

```
  DRIVER
  Why did you allow a enemy of the state
  to escape?

  COL LANDA
  Oh, I don't think the state is in too
  much danger, do you?

  DRIVER
  I suppose not.

  COL LANDA
  I'm glad you see it my way. Besides,
  not putting a bullet in the back of a
  fifteen year old girl, and allowing
  her to escape, our not nessessarlly [sic]
  the same thing. She's a young girl, no food,
  no shelter, no shoes, who's just witnessed
  the massacre of her entire family.
  She may not survive the night. And after
  word spreads about what happened today,
  it's highly unlikely she will find any
  willing farmers to extend her aid.
  If I had to guess her fate, I'd say she'll
  probably be turned in by some neighbour.
  Or, she'll be spotted by some German
  soldier. Or, we'll find her body in the
  woods, dead from starvation or exposure.
  Or, perhaps-she'll survive. She will
  elude capture. She will escape to America.
  She will move to New York city.
  Where she will be elected, President of
  the United States
```

And in the spirit of the movie, Landa is The Jew Hunter. He's good at what's he's doing, but he also likes it. An escaped jewish girl is another prey for him. So he can hunt a little longer. For me it was part of showing Nazis as not "following orders", but people who are evil on their own. Who find and seek pleasure in tormenting other people.

Quote copied from [www.scriptslug.com](https://scriptslug.com/scripts/inglourious-basterds)

Comment: Landa has a habit of doing _horrible_ things in a _nice and courteous_ manner. Letting Shosana escape fits his profile perfectly: she's likely to get captured anyway, and this way he doesn't need to drop the pretense of civility.

Comment: @Flater that could be an answer on its own :)

Comment: @JAD: I can't do better than Landa's own explanation of why he let her run away :)

Comment: can you also mention the source where you copied the screenplay form